# Want to check if a variable is present in an array or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of countries.

```
var countriesArray = ["United States","Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Argentina","Australia","Austria", "Bahrain"];
```

And i am getting value of a country in a variable.

```
     <div id="location" class="editable-item">
    <dl><dt>Location</dt><dd><span class="locality"><a href="/vsearch/p?f_G=in%3A7127&amp;trk=prof-0-ovw-location" name="location" title="Find other members in Bengaluru Area, India">Bengaluru Area, India</a></span></dd><dt>Industry</dt><dd class="industry"><a href="/vsearch/p?f_I=11&amp;trk=prof-0-ovw-industry" name="industry" title="Find other members in this industry">Management Consulting</a></dd></dl></div>
    var place = document.querySelector('#location .locality a').innerHTML;
    var splitPlace = place.split(',');
    var length = splitPlace.length;
    var lastValue = splitPlace[length - 1] ;
```

here lastValue  has value Algeria.

I want to check if the value in lastValue variable is present in countriesArray or not.For this i used

```
console.log($.inArray(lastValue, countriesArray));
```

But it is always returning -1 whether or not value is present in array or not.Suggest the mistake in this or give some other way of doing it. Also i want that the comparison of values is done irrespective of case.

Comment: Show function splitPlace

Comment: i have shown splitplace above

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra. this doesnot help. We need to know the contents of `splitPlace`.

Comment: <div id="location" class="editable-item"><dl><dt>Location</dt><dd><span class="locality"><a href="/vsearch/p?f_G=in%3A7127&amp;trk=prof-0-ovw-location" name="location" title="Find other members in Bengaluru Area, India">Bengaluru Area, India</a></span></dd><dt>Industry</dt><dd class="industry"><a href="/vsearch/p?f_I=11&amp;trk=prof-0-ovw-industry" name="industry" title="Find other members in this industry">Management Consulting</a></dd></dl></div>

Comment: i edited the question and give the html from where the value is getting picked

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra. In your question you said, `lastValue` is `Algeria`. But its `India`, see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/crma4638/

Comment: in countries array i have names of all countries but here mentioned just few countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `lastValue` is `" India"`. It starts with a space character. You should trim the string, using jQuery `$.trim` or `String.prototype.trim` function. Also the array doesn't have `India` element so `$.inArray` should still return `-1`.

```
$.inArray($.trim(lastValue), countriesArray);
```

In case that the search should be case insensitive, you can use the `String.prototype.toLowerCase` or `String.prototype.toUpperCase` method:

```
$.inArray(lastValue.trim().toLowerCase(), countriesArray.map(function(el) {
    return el.toLowerCase();
}));
```

Comment: this worked ...but for case insensitive i have to manually convert into lowercase for comparision

Comment: in countries array i have names of all countries but here mentioned just few countries.

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra I have updated the answer with an example for the case-insensitive case. If you want to support IE8  you can use jQuery `$.trim` and `$.map` functions instead of the above functions! `$.trim(lastValue).toLowerCase() ...`

Answer (score 2):

- Use a lowercase array and [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to be case insensitive.
- Remember to [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the value too

Here is a **COMPLETE** example

```js
var countriesArray = ["united states", "afghanistan", "albania", "algeria", "argentina", "australia", "austria", "bahrain"];
$(function() {
  var place = $('#location .locality a').html();
  var splitPlace = place.split(',');
  var length = splitPlace.length;
  var lastValue = $.trim(splitPlace[length - 1]);
  var found = $.inArray(lastValue.toLowerCase(), countriesArray)!=-1;
  alert(lastValue+" was "+(found?"found":"not found"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="location"><span class="locality"><a href=#">Algeria,Argentina,Australia,Austria,Bahrain</a></span></div>
```

---

Native alternative to [$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) - [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
    var last = countriesArray[countriesArray.length-1];
    alert(countriesArray.indexOf(last.toLowerCase().trim())!=-1)

Comment: see question ..it is returning index in countriesarray but i want to check if a value i am getting in a variable is present in countriesArray or not

Comment: @BhawnaMalhotra I am quite disappointed that you accepted another answer. I was first to answer and updated my answer for every changed specification your came with. I added trim last on a guess since you had not provided an example of your actual data that would have let me see you had leading spaces in your countries.

Comment: the first answer you give didn't work as expected even before when i edited the question thats why. But don't worry your solution will help my codders . :)

Comment: It did not work as expected on YOUR data on your computer since I had not thought of adding trim because there was no example of how your actual data looked. I then added the trim at the same time as the others added theirs, but before that I had working versions that just happened not to fully work on your unpublished data. My answer is now a drop-in solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following should do it:

```
if(countriesArray.indexOf(lastValue) >= 0 )
{
   alert("present");
}
else 
{
   alert("not present");
}
```

If you want it to be case insensitive than better iterate

```
for(var i=0; i<lastValue.length; i++)
{
   if(lastValue.toLowerCase().trim() == countriesArray[i].toLowerCase().trim())
   {
       alert("present");
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: not working .also it want to make case insensitive match

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `.trim()` to trim the value as it may contains leading and trailing spaces:

```
if(countriesArray.toString().indexOf(lastValue.trim())>=0) {
  alert(lastValue)
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wb550dLp/1/)